# Reading images from div in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html, image-preloader

I have created a index page

```
<body>
    <div>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
   <style>
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
</style>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
    
     <input type="submit" name="Post" />
}
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }

            var reader = new FileReader();

            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                      '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index_Post(FormCollection collection)
        {
            var tlist = collection["list"];
            return View();
        }
```

When images are uploaded , this is how it looks like in chrome

[image]

but with view source I am getting below rendered output

```
<form action="/imgUpload" method="post"><input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

How can I read all images from this div and save them to disk ?

**EDIT**

Example script: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

same issue I can see over there

Answer (score 0):

first change the form helper

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action",
                       "Controller", FormMethod.Post,
                        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

then in controller you can access all posted files from `Request.Files` or you can change the controller's arguments

Comment: This didn't work. I guess the reason is that nothing is getting stored inside <output> tag.

Comment: "list" ?! you need to change it to the name of the upload element in html, or just use index, or with AllKeys get all of the keys and run a foreach loop or something like that

Comment: I have used this

**var tlist = Request.Files.AllKeys;

            foreach (var list in tlist)
            {
                list.ToString();
            }**
This loop is running only one time and list.ToString() is giving me "files[]"